# sort xml based on attribute in python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to sort the xml based on code in the field tag.

Below is the code implementation I tried but it is printing only one field

Sorting should be mainly done on code attribute

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlData = '''<data>
<values>
<field code="6">rst</field>
<show>qwerty6</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="5">opq</field>
<show>qwerty5</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="4">klm</field>
<show>qwerty4</show>
</values>
<values>
<field code="3">hij</field>
<show>qwerty3</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="2">efg</field>
<show>qwerty2</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="1">abc</field>
<show>qwerty1</show>
</values>
</data>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
myvalues = tree.find('values')

for el in myvalues:
    el[:] = sorted(el, key=lambda e: (e.tag, e.attrib['code']))
tree[:] = myvalues

xmlstr = ET.tostring(tree, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
print(xmlstr.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the redundant loop and pass `myvalues` directly to `sorted`. When you call `sorted`, it will iterate over `data` `Element`.

The `lambda` should look like this:

```
lambda value: value[0].get("code")
```

which will get the first child (`field`) from the `values` and return the `code` to use as a sorting key.

Then, you can just regenerate the XML from `myvalues` directly - there's no need to assign anything back to `tree`.

The following should work for you:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlData = """
<data>
<values>
<field code="6">rst</field>
<show>qwerty6</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="5">opq</field>
<show>qwerty5</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="4">klm</field>
<show>qwerty4</show>
</values>
<values>
<field code="3">hij</field>
<show>qwerty3</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="2">efg</field>
<show>qwerty2</show>
<chip/>
<normal/>
</values>
<values>
<field code="1">abc</field>
<show>qwerty1</show>
</values>
</data>
"""

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlData))
myvalues = tree.getroot()
myvalues[:] = sorted(myvalues, key=lambda value: value[0].get("code"))
xmlstr = ET.tostring(myvalues, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
print(xmlstr.decode("utf-8"))
```

Which gives the output:

```
<data>
<values>
<field code="1">abc</field>
<show>qwerty1</show>
</values>
<values>
<field code="2">efg</field>
<show>qwerty2</show>
<chip />
<normal />
</values>
<values>
<field code="3">hij</field>
<show>qwerty3</show>
<chip />
<normal />
</values>
<values>
<field code="4">klm</field>
<show>qwerty4</show>
</values>
<values>
<field code="5">opq</field>
<show>qwerty5</show>
<chip />
<normal />
</values>
<values>
<field code="6">rst</field>
<show>qwerty6</show>
<chip />
<normal />
</values>
</data>
```